# Flink SQL, how to get the first record and the last record by eventtime in kafka data flow and store it to a DB(such as GP, MySQL)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

`Flink SQL`, how to get the first record and the last record by eventtime in `Kafka` data flow and store it to a DB(such as `MySQL`)?

Addition, if new record in `Kafka` data flow coming, we should update the record in `MySQL`.

1. Assumption, records in `Kafka` are as follows:

```
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:00:00', 'appear_page': 5}
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:05:00', 'appear_page': 10}
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:10:00', 'appear_page': 15}
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:05:00', 'appear_page': 15}      
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:15:00', 'appear_page': 20}
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:00:00', 'appear_page': 12}
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:10:00''appear_page': 18}
```

2. By `Flink SQL`, the results I expected are as follows:

```
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:00:00', 'appear_page': 5}
    {'word': 'hello', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:15:00', 'appear_page': 20}
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:00:00', 'appear_page': 12}
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 16:10:00', 'appear_page': 18}
```

3. We store these record in `MySQL`, assump that the result are as follows,

```
    |    word    |    first_appearance_time    |    first_appearance_page    |    last_appearance_time    |    last_appearance_page    |
    |    hello   |    2020-12-04 16:00:00      |            5                |    2020-12-04 16:15:00     |             20             |
    |    are     |    2020-12-04 16:00:00      |            12               |    2020-12-04 16:10:00     |             18             |
```

4. If a new record in `Kafka` is coming,

```
    {'word': 'are', 'eventtime': '2020-12-04 17:18:00', 'appear_page': 30}
```

5. I hope we can update the record of `are` in `MySQL`, the updating result are as follows:

```
    |    word    |    first_appearance_time    |    first_appearance_page    |    last_appearance_time    |    last_appearance_page    |
    |    hello   |    2020-12-04 16:00:00      |            5                |    2020-12-04 16:15:00     |             20             |
    |    are     |    2020-12-04 16:00:00      |            12               |    2020-12-04 17:18:00     |             30             |
```

I have some trouble in the 2th and 5th step, can anyone give some idea?

Comment: Could you show what you have already done?

Comment: Couldn't you look at every record and insert all fields when the record doesn't exist, then update last seen fields for when it is? You're going to have to check for existence in the table anyway... Basically, there is no "last event" in a continuous Kafka topic, so thinking of it that way is likely flawed

Comment: I disagree, last in a continuous stream is well defined. It just means "the most recent based on some notion of time".

Comment: @ArvidHeise, Sorry, I had no idea how to deal with the problem, so  I gave the scenary and hoped get some advice.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yeah, I also considered the scheme, but it will cause great load on DB. Besides, UPDATE operation is complex.

Comment: @Seth, you are right. It's  what I want express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deduplication with ordering by rowtime would be the easiest way, but this is supported in 1.12.  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/sql/queries.html#deduplication

```sql
CREATE TABLE src (
  word STRING,
  eventtime TIMESTAMP(3),
  appear_page INT,
  WATERMARK FOR eventtime AS eventtime - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  ...
);

-- get last row by word key
SELECT word, eventtime, appear_page
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY word ORDER BY eventtime DESC) AS rownum
  FROM src
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This query should also work in 1.11, but is not optimized into a deduplication, but a TopN operator which is less efficient.

Comment: Thanks, it does can get the first record and the last record of every word sepearatly, but it seems can't get them at the same time in Flink SQL. Whereas, Postgre SQL can deal with it,   this maybe the limitation of Flink SQL.

Comment: @Sky, sorry, what do you mean "can't get them at the same time in Flink SQL"? Do you mean the above query can't work in Flink SQL?

Comment: it does work in Flink SQL. I mean we can only get the first record or the last record of every word at every time by above method. But I want to get the first record and the last record of every word at a single SQL. eg.: select word, eventtime, appear_page from( select *, row_number() over (partition by word order by eventtime desc) as rownum_last, row_number() over (partiton by word order by eventtime asc) as rownum_first) where rownum_last = 1 or row_number_first = 1;   Flink SQL not support the way with two WINDOW function, but GP is OK.

Comment: Oh, I see, we can by SQL JOIN clause to deal with the situation.

Comment: In fact, I have solved this problem by Java  DataStream API later. Thanks again, you give me a new solution.